# Dynamically fill a post custom field with post publish date

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I created a custom field using Advanced Custom Fields (but I think ACF is optional) and I want him to dynamically fill the publish post date when I publish a post.

Example :

If I publish a post today, I want when the action of publishing is done to find `30/09/2020` in my custom field
If I schedule my post for tomorrow then I want to find tomorrow `01/10/2020` in my custom field.

Same idea if I publish my article at an earlier date.

I already tried this (in relation with ACF plugin but any other type of solution is find to me) :

```
add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post');
function my_acf_save_post( $post_id ) { 
    $value = get_the_date();
    update_field('name_of_my_custom_field', $value, $post_id);
}
```

But I always get today’s date and not the real published date.

One other thing, I don’t want my custom field to be updated when I will update my post in the future. So I thought about a condition like: IF my custom field is filled with data THEN I do nothing but I am not able to do it.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 1):

When you get the date with function `get_the_date()` you need to pass a $post object or ID as a second parameter:

```
$date = get_the_date( $date_format, $post );
```

The first parameter here is the PHP date format. The second - Post ID or WP_Post object

Here is an example that should work:

```
add_action( 'acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post' ); 

function my_acf_save_post( $post_id ) {
    $date = get_the_date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $post_id );

    update_field( 'your_meta_key', $date, $post_id ); 
}
```

Check the documentation on `get_the_date()` function https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_date/

Comment: Thanks for your help, I change my function like that :
`add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post');
function my_acf_save_post( $post_id ) { 
 $date_format = get_option( 'date_format' );
    $value = get_the_date($date_format, $post_id);
    update_field('name_of_my_custom_field', $value, $post_id);
}`
But I still always get today's date when I try to schedule a post for example.

Comment: What type of ACF field do you use? Is it a regular Text field, or Date Time Picker? @JonathanAryup

Comment: For the moment it is a date type of field, but i can switch to a text field if this is easier.

Comment: I've added an example to the answer, it worked for me with both Text and Date Time Picker field

Comment: It works fine for me too thanks a lot !